# Query regarding "CGImageCreateWithImageInRect"

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa

im trying to cut a image and mask it....that im able to do successfully..but the program exits after few minutes with 101 status

```
- (void) maskImage {

        if(scopeOn==1){

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.bounds.size);
    [self.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    cachedImage=[UIImage imageNamed:@"loop.png"];
    cachedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

     imageRef = [cachedImage CGImage];

     subImage = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(imageRef, CGRectMake(scopeLoc.x-25, scopeLoc.y-25, 50, 50));
     xMaskedImage = CGImageCreateWithMask(subImage, mask);
    zoomImg.image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:xMaskedImage]; // retImage;
    [zoomImg setCenter:scopeLoc];

    [self addSubview:zoomImg];

    CGImageRelease(subImage);
            CGImageRelease(xMaskedImage);

}
```

}

this is the code that im using....since im not allocating explicit memory my guess is that CGImageCreateWithImageInRect function is allocating memory but it is not being released...this function is called after every 0.1 secs...so eventually a large amount of memoey is allocated(i have seen this in memory leak performance monitor)

So is there any other way in which i can achive the same wihtout this function??

Comment: do you ever remove subviews from self?

Comment: when the user cancels the zooming operation then....

Answer (score 4):

Are you releasing the subImage variable later? CGImageCreateWithImageInRect follows the "Create" rule from CoreFoundation, and thus requires you to release the variable later.

Comment: As suggested i released the CGImageRef object, no memory leaks occured but it is still consuming memory...it goes upto 40mb and then it exits with status 101...

I have update the whole function in the post that i have been using, this function is being called per 0.1sec...

please help.....

Comment: what about xMaskedImage? it may have a similar problem

Comment: yea did it...but no change it still exists  :(

Comment: Where is "mask" coming from? Is that also being properly released when it's no longer being used? I can't see any other missed releases from this method, and would assume they're somewhere else. If you run instruments you should be able to narrow down where it's coming from.

Answer (score 1):

You can release the memory allocated for your subImage and xMaskedImage by following

```
    CGImageRelease(subImage);           // Decrements the retain count of a bitmap image.
    subImage=nil;
CGImageRelease(xMaskedImage);
xMaskedImage=nil;
```

It will definitely solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try adding a test for if `zoomImg` is already a subview:

```
if (zoomImg.superview != self)
    [self addSubview:zoomImg];
```

although this is a fairly long shot.